# How to parse simple times with am/pm

Tags: java

I'm trying to parse some times with Java 8 APIs and it's failing miserably. Clearly I'm missing something basic. Here's the simple example:

```
    final DateTimeFormatter simpleFormat = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().
            appendPattern("h[h][:mm]a").
            parseCaseInsensitive().
            parseDefaulting(ChronoField.MINUTE_OF_HOUR, 0).
            parseDefaulting(ChronoField.AMPM_OF_DAY, 0).
            toFormatter();

    simpleFormat.parse("9am", LocalTime::from);
    simpleFormat.parse("11am", LocalTime::from);

    simpleFormat.parse("9pm", LocalTime::from);
    simpleFormat.parse("11pm", LocalTime::from);
```

That gives me:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '9pm' could not be parsed at index 1
```

I'd like to also be able to parse times like "12:30 am", which is why the format is a little more complex than it has to be for the 9am case. The case insensitive parsing is there because my data has am/pm, not AM/PM, and I added the defaulting bits after reading a lot of other people having problems with parsing am/pm times, so it's a bit of cargo-culting unfortunately.

Some other format strings I've tried, just to rule them out:

```
"h[:mm]a"
"ha"
```

The same error occurs, although the index position changes.

TIA!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You specify a format that requires hours to be specified with two digits but then you only supply one.

Either use `09am` or change your format to only require one digit `h[:mm]a`.

```
DateTimeFormatter simpleFormat = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().
    parseCaseInsensitive().
    appendPattern("h[:mm]a").
    parseDefaulting(ChronoField.MINUTE_OF_HOUR, 0).
    parseDefaulting(ChronoField.AMPM_OF_DAY, 0).
    toFormatter();

System.err.println(simpleFormat.parse("09AM", LocalTime::from));
System.err.println(simpleFormat.parse("09:12AM", LocalTime::from));
System.err.println(simpleFormat.parse("9AM", LocalTime::from));
```

Which gives output

```
09:00
09:12
09:00
```

Notice that `parseCaseInsensitive()` must go before `appendPattern()`.

Comment: Ok, the order of operations for the builder seems to matter. I've made another update.

Comment: Your answer is really close, and I'd like to give you credit for it! Let me see if I can edit it and get it to what I just got working.

Comment: Welp, you didn't accept my edit -- so I'll make a comment for future readers. parseCaseInsensitive works as advertised _as long as_ it goes before appendPattern.

Comment: @JamesWaldrop I updated the example and added a notice about the importance of order.